# Abstracting and indexing of a journal

Tags: mathematics, journals

If a mathematics journal abstracting and indexing is

$1.$ Mathematical Reviews

$2.$ Zentralblatt MATH

$3.$ Scopus

then how  good is that  journal ? Actually I communicate my paper in a well know journal. They reject it and recommended this journal whose indexing I mention above.

Comment: Note "MathSciNet" is the name of the on-line version of "Mathematical Reviews".  Does "Mathematical Reviews" itself even exist any more?

Comment: @GEdgar sir I don’t know . I just copied from journal site .

Answer (score 2):

For mathematics papers, 1. and 2. are the choice. They are of top quality. On the other hand, 3. claims to cover "all flelds of research". I know nothing about their quality of indexing.

A mathematical journal **not** covered by 1. and 2. is likely not a serious journal.  (The other option is that it is a very new journal and will be indexed in the future.)

Comment: Scopus doesn't include many lower tire journals. Scopus is also a good collection i would say.

Comment: @GEdgar yes it is 2019 starting journal.